# Position "list-group" on the right side, while "cards" are on the left side, Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a bit confused while learning and putting together website with Bootstrap grid system. I'm making a menu that consists of 3 blocks - "cards" and one more fixed (that follows when you're scrolling) "list-group".
Have been trying using float:right etc., but when I change something that pulls the "list-group" right, everything breaks.

[image]

HTML:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="side">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3" style="background:red">
            <div class="list-group">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Dapibus ac</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Morbi leo risus</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3" style="background:cyan">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Text.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-3" style="background:yellow">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Text.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-3" style="background:orange">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Text.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="w-100"></div>

          <div class="col-sm-3" style="background:red">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Text.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Appreciating every helpful answer I get!

Comment: I’m confused as to the exact behavior you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @CoryKleiser I'm trying to place the "list-group" panel (seen on the left-top side of screenshot) on the right side next to "row's" or "cards" and it should be fixed and following when scrolling. I don't have an idea how to make it.

Comment: [link](http://prntscr.com/jb6tjc) Here I can see that the "list-group" has taken the whole upper space. Is there a way to make it go back to the right side?

Comment: Hey @Berisko I've added an answer below. I think I understand what you're going for, let me know if that gets you close to where you want to be or if I completely missed the mark :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out this code

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.side {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top:0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 250px;
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.content {
  margin-right: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="side">
            <div class="list-group">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Dapibus ac</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Morbi leo risus</a>
            </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3" style="background:cyan">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Text.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-3" style="background:yellow">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Text.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-3" style="background:orange">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Text.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-3" style="background:red">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Text.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Using bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="container">
       <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-8">
             <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6" style="background:cyan">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Text.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-6" style="background:yellow">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Text.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-6" style="background:orange">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Text.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-6" style="background:red">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Text.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3  col-sm-4">
                <div class="side">
            <div class="list-group">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Dapibus ac</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Morbi leo risus</a>
            </div>
      </div>

          </div>
       <div>

   
      
      

    </div>
```

Comment: The same problem I had. When something is changed, it breaks.

Comment: what problem @Berisko

Comment: tell me your problem. i am happy to help you :)

Comment: You need to clarify your question @Berisko. Otherwise it’s hard for the community to help.

Comment: @CoryKleiser I answered your comment, should be clear now. Sorry

Comment: @patelarpan When I added your provided code, the "list-group" went to left side and it's squished, the text is out of the box etc.

Comment: where you want your list group?

Comment: in relative to body or container

Comment: I made it so it's as wide as 12 columns of Bootstrap grid. 9 for cards and 3 for list-group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169984/discussion-between-patelarpan-and-berisko).

Answer (score 1):

So I've gotten the best results with supplemental CSS. First you'll have to make a couple changes to your html. First, change the class on your list to `col-sm-12` instead of `col-sm-3`. This is going will make sense when you add the below CSS. The second change to you HTML would be to change your `container` to `container-fluid`. This is not necessary but it makes it look cleaner in my opinion. Once you have that set up you can add the following CSS to fix your list to the side of the page at about the center vertically:

```
@media(min-width:576px){
  .side{
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 40%;
    width:25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding-left:15px;
  }
}
```

This css will fix the list so it stays put, even while scrolling. The `right: 0;` fixes it to the right side of the page and the and the `top:40%;` pushes it down to about the center of the page; you can play around with the `top` value to get it exactly where you want depending on the length of the list. Here is a code snippet of this so you can see it in action:

```css
@media(min-width:576px) {
  .side {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 40%;
    width: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="side">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12" style="background:red">
        <div class="list-group">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Dapibus ac</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Morbi leo risus</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="background:cyan">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Text.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3" style="background:yellow">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Text.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3" style="background:orange">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Text.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="w-100"></div>

      <div class="col-sm-3" style="background:red">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Text.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps you out.